# Specifying a layout and a template in a standalone (not rails) ruby app, using slim or haml

Tags: ruby, haml, slim-lang

I'm trying to do something like this in a standalone (not rails) app:

layout.slim:

```
h1 Hello
.content
  = yield
```

show.slim:

```
= object.name
= object.description
```

I can't figure out how to specify a layout and a template. Is this possible with slim (or haml)? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The layout.slim file looks like:

```
h1 Hello
.content
  == yield
```

The contents.slim file looks like:

```
= name
```

This can be shortened, but I separated to individual steps for explanation purposes.

```
require 'slim'

# Simple class to represent an environment
class Env
  attr_accessor :name
end

# Intialize it
env = Env.new
# Set the variable we reference in contents.slim
env.name = "test this layout"

# Read the layout file in as a string
layout = File.open("layout.slim", "rb").read

# Read the contents file in as a string
contents = File.open("contents.slim", "rb").read

# Create new template object with the layout
l = Slim::Template.new { layout }

# Render the contents passing in the environment: env
# so that it can resolve: = name
c = Slim::Template.new { contents }.render(env)

# Render the layout passing it the rendered contents
# as the block. This is what yield in layout.slim will get
puts l.render{ c }
```

This will output:

```
<h1>Hello</h1><div class="content">test this layout</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got pretty close from the docs but I was confused about what scope was. I also had to do `== yield` instead of `= yield`

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that, Slim escapes HTML by default. I updated the code.

Comment: Use `File.read("layout.slim")` instead of `File.open("contents.slim", "rb").read`. The latter relies on GC/finalizer to close the file which may or may not happen whenever.