# Passing data to layout templates with Slim-lang

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I have a problem with passing data to Slim templates. I have the following **working** code (using information from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058993/specifying-a-layout-and-a-template-in-a-standalone-not-rails-ruby-app-using-s)):

```
l = Slim::Template.new { @layout } # How to pass data here?

_p = Slim::Template.new { @post_text }.render(Object.new, :post => post)
# Here passing data (post) works fine     -----------------^

out = l.render{ _p }
```

What I have in templates:

**layout.slim**:

```
doctype
  html
  head
    title =my_title # < I cannot pass any parameters to this file
  body
    ==yield
```

**post_text.slim**:

```
-unless post.nil?
  h1 =post[:title]
  hr
  =post[:text]
-else
  h2 No posts
```

My question is how to pass parameters to layout template in my case?

Comment: so it is not possible to call the last render wir options? like ```l.render(Object.new, :my_title => 'bla') { _p }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[phoet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100731/phoet) should have written his comment as an answer because it helped:

```
l.render(Object.new, :my_title => 'bla') { _p }
```