# How to use Slim directly in ruby

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I would like to create a basic ruby script that renders Slim templates into html (This would eventually be part of a larger project). Ideally I would like to use the HTML produced within the script.

I understand this is possible using TILT (as shown in the SLIM [README](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#tilt)) where it says the following:

---

Slim uses Tilt to compile the generated code. If you want to use the Slim template directly, you can use the Tilt interface.

```
 Tilt.new['template.slim'].render(scope)
 Slim::Template.new('template.slim', optional_option_hash).render(scope)
 Slim::Template.new(optional_option_hash) { source }.render(scope)
```

The optional option hash can have to options which were documented in the section above. The scope is the object in which the template code is executed.

---

However, I'm still unable to successfully run this. Therefore, I was wondering if someone could help me by producing a working example.

**EDIT** (this has recently been edited further ):

I have played about with the code quite a bit but I keep on getting the following error:

```
 undefined local variable or method `source' for main:Object (NameError)
```

This is what i'm running:

```
require 'slim'

# I'm not sure about the next two lines...
optional_option_hash = {}
scope = Object.new    

Tilt.new('template.slim').render(scope)
Slim::Template.new('template.slim', optional_option_hash).render(scope)
Slim::Template.new(optional_option_hash) { source }.render(scope)
```

Many Thanks for all your help.

Comment: "Unable to sucessfully run this" is not an adequate description of the problem.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I have now edited the post to show details of what I had done so far

Comment: Clicking through to the page for [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt), it looks like the current 2.0 release has different syntax. In particular it should be `Tilt.new('template.slim')`, which is why you're getting the `ArgumentError`.

Comment: @Max, Many Thanks, that solved that error, I now get uninitialised method or variable for scope and if I made scope = Object.new then I get uninsitialised method or variable for source...

Comment: @IsmailM I think you need to stop blindly copy-pasting code and read about how to use these libararies. And that new error message _clearly_ tells you what's wrong: `source` is not defined.

Comment: @Max the problem is that I'm not sure what `source` and `scope` should be... Are they variables (containing exactly what) or are they Objects (of what)..

Comment: It sounds like you basically want someone to explain how to use these libraries. That isn't exactly what Stack Overflow is about. I don't know how to use them. I could read the documentation and make a small example for you, but it's not clear that that would actually answer your question.

Comment: @Max I can use this library (with Sinatra or other) but cannot use it directly in ruby... I have looked at the Docs and only found a few lines showing that it was possible (but they seemed to be incomplete)... I looked elsewhere and could not find an example... I have spent a few hours trying to play with the code and did not get anywhere... So I wen to StackOverFlow to see if someone else has done this before and could provide be with a working example...

Comment: @Max just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058993/specifying-a-layout-and-a-template-in-a-standalone-not-rails-ruby-app-using-s) which does what I want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Specifying a layout and a template in a standalone (not rails) ruby app, using slim or haml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058993/specifying-a-layout-and-a-template-in-a-standalone-not-rails-ruby-app-using-s)

This is what I ended up using:

```
require 'slim'

# Simple class to represent an environment
class Env
  attr_accessor :name
end

scope = Env.new
scope.name = "test this layout"

layout =<<EOS
h1 Hello
.content
  = yield
EOS

contents =<<EOS
  = name
EOS

layout = Slim::Template.new { layout }
content = Slim::Template.new { contents }.render(scope)

puts layout.render{ content }
```

For the scope, you can put in modules/classes or even `self`.

Answer (score 2):

Quick essentials of

```
  module SlimRender

    def slim(template, variables = {})
      template = template.to_s
      template += '.slim' unless template.end_with? '.slim'
      template = File.read("#{ROOT}/app/views/#{template}", encoding: 'UTF-8')
      Slim::Template.new { template }.render OpenStruct.new(variables)
    end

  end
```

Include `SlimRender` to your class and:

```
  def render_something
    slim 'streams/scoreboard', scores: '1-2'
  end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with content_for

any idea how to include the rails helpers in here?